# Where can I get free FX options chain data

Tags: fx, market-data, data, tick-data

Basically title. Can either be through an API or easily downloadable as a CSV file. Every source I find either have options chain data but not for FX, has historical FX data but not an actual chain with strikes and expiries, or they have both but the data can't be easily downloaded.

Comment: Probably good to have realistic expectations. If you are looking for historical option chain data, it is usually a lot of data, and therefore, not free. I never found a free resource with good historical EOD option data for more than one day back. To put into perspective, where I work, we pay around 1000 USD per month for EOD updates (including 5min intraday), and for the set of historical data the price was around 50k USD for 10TB of data.

Comment: @Valter It doesn't have to be intraday data. I just need snapshots at different points in time for testing.